# How do integrate equation with two derivatives?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

I need to integrate next equation:

$$m \cdot dz=\left(  r-z(r-1) \right)^4 \cdot \dfrac{dp}{dz} \cdot \left(   p+k+\dfrac{k^2}{p}\right)dz$$

where $m$, $r$, $k$ are constants and $p=p(z)$. How to integrate this equation-its right side? Would be appropriate to cut terms $dz$ because of the term $r-z(r-1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m= \left( r-z \left( r-1 \right)  \right) ^{4} \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}z}}p \left( z \right)  \right)  \left( p \left( z \right) +k+{
\frac {{k}^{2}}{p \left( z \right) }} \right)$$

$${m \left( p \left( z \right) +k+{\frac {{k}^{2}}{p \left( z \right) }}
 \right) ^{-1}}= \left( r-z \left( r-1 \right)  \right) ^{4}{\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}z}}p \left( z \right)$$

$${\frac {m}{ \left( r-z \left( r-1 \right)  \right) ^{4}}}= \left( p
 \left( z \right) +k+{\frac {{k}^{2}}{p \left( z \right) }} \right) {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}z}}p \left( z \right)$$

$$\int \!{\frac {m}{ \left( r-z \left( r-1 \right)  \right) ^{4}}}
\,{\rm d}z=\int \!p(z)+k+{\frac {{k}^{2}}{p(z)}}\,{\rm d}p(z)
$$

$$-1/3\,{\frac {m}{ \left(  \left( 1-r \right) z+r \right) ^{3} \left( 1
-r \right) }}=1/2\,{p(z)}^{2}+kp(z)+{k}^{2}\ln  \left( p(z) \right) +C
$$

Comment: Thanks, it works, but is the result of $\int \dfrac{dz}{(r-z(r-z))^4}$ that what you wrote, or $\dfrac{1}{3(r-1)(r-z(r-z))^3}$ ?

Comment: It is as it need to be now.